# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when clf.fit

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'd like to train data given `df X and Y`; `X` is feature while `Y` is target variable.

First turn df into array

```
X = X1.values
Y = Y1.values

print(type(X))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print(type(Y))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And this is X and Y looks like for the first two rows:

```
print(X)

[[1 100.0 10 -8.465 0 0.332 0.0565 0.47100000000000003 0.696 0.521 292987
  4.0 0.302 0.0 [1, 2] [1] [1, 1, 1, 1] [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
[1 175.483 6 -8.205 0 0.364 0.128 0.564 0.504 0.705 239320 4.0 0.0752 0.0
  [1, 2] [1] [1, 1, 1, 1] [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]


print(Y)

[1 0]
```

However when I tried to train data: `clf.fit(X,Y)`
Errors like:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I think problem comes from vectors inside X; what could I solve it?
Thanks!

=================================================
Or I think question is:
How to process dataframe that contain both float numbers and vectors in order for data training?

```
               Col_A         Col_B           Col_C
0               0.0          [1, 2]           [1]     
1               0.0          [1, 2]           [1]
```

Comment: What is that strange format of X and Y? Mixed arrays and float numbers?

Comment: Yea, this doesn't look right. Why are there nested arrays in your X?

Comment: Hi guys, see my edit please! Basically my problem is my dataframe contain both float number and vectors. What should I do to process this for data training?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your columns containing arrays into individual columns before passing the values to the learner. A simple (manual) way would be:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
   Col_A   Col_B
0      0  [1, 2]
1      0  [3, 4]

In [19]: pd.concat([df['Col_A'], df['Col_B'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).values
Out[19]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Basically I'm doing NLP, converting text into vectors; so [1,2] represent, for example, music type; is it really Okay to break the list and mix with other items for training?

Comment: A normal classifier will only accept a plain vector as features per item. So you have to come up with such a representation and the information contained in the flat representation is still the same.